Extracting text from pdf with custom font
I have a voluminous PDF file containing text with specific scientific notation. I'm trying to extract the text using pdfplumber.
At first, I noticed that certain symbols are extracted as capital Latin characters, while technical symbols like '[' and codes e.g., (cid:8) are also present. Moreover, the same code is often displayed in the file with different symbols. I solved this problem by collecting not only the text representation of each symbol but also the name of the font.
However, I now wonder if it is possible to extract the encoding directly from the PDF file. I mean getting information in the format: {'symbol': 'e', 'font': 'ejdeij+4brane'} displayed as something.
Here's an example pdf. As you might see ('(cid:8)', 'EJDEHH+6Brane') stands here for ḁ̃. All I want to know is if it is possible to not check every pair manually. This information must be somewhere deeply in the file structure, and what I search is a way to extract it.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to SO.
If you are willing to provide a representative sample PDF I can test and probably suggest an alternative method. There are other libraries and tools that can trace PDF drawing operation calls and provide output about which character is drawn at what position and which font. Example output:
'   



'

Oh, I've ended up with just collecting a set of all unique pairs like (symbol, fontname) with information what page and line they are located on. After that I've simply manually checked what actual symbol these pairs stand for.

But I really appreciate your desire to help. There was a comment with some advises and ideas in this thread but the person who has originally posted it deleted it just as my answer to them. In that answer I provided an example pdf. Here you go. As you might see ('(cid:8)', 'EJDEHH+6Brane') stands here for ḁ̃. All I want to know is if it is possible to not check every pair manually. This information must be somewhere deeply in .pdf file structure and what I search is a way to extract it.

Text in a PDF is very simple if you understand Computer Aided Design and Draughting (CADD), whilst in some cases it may be more akin to Word Processing it does not have to be sequential.
A word like Abracadabra can be written in a PDF in any order such as A a a a a b b c d r r or any other XY XY XY sequence and each be allocated different styles or binary encoding.

-27 0 Td(A)' 25 20 Td(a)' 17 20 Td(a)' 18 20 Td(a)' 23 20 Td(a)'
-72 20 Td(b)' 58 20 Td(b)'
-35 20 Td(c)'
17 20 Td(d)'
26.5 20 Td(r)' -58 20 Td(r)'
40 TL

for the offered example
The graphics XY placement for 27 tḁ̃:j are presented on the surface from binary code in the pages data, as many separate bytes and named encodings too.

The "style applied to either side is TimesNewRoman but the ḁ̃ is prefixed as object 38 6Brane which is stored as object 54 sub-set /FontName/EJDEHH+6Brane/FontFile3 53 and Fontfile 3 is thus drawn using objects from object 53. So what about the real placements in the page?
/Font<</T1_0 36 0 R/T1_1 37 0 R/T1_2 38 0 R/T1_3 39 0 R/T1_4 40 0 R/T1_5 51 0 R
So 3rd font is /T1_2 38 0 R hence any text prefixed with /T1_2 will be styled on screen as 6Brane this makes it easy to find where it is positioned in the human decoded binary stream as Character IDentity hexadecimal 8 <08> seen sandwiched between 27 t and :j
0 Tc .65 Tw T* (27 t) Tj 0 Tw
/T1_2 1 Tf 12 0 0 12 107.6929 860.328 Tm <08> Tj -.0001 Tc
/T1_1 1 Tf 12 0 0 12 113.0329 860.328 Tm (:j) Tj

But we want to know what all those binary stream 0011000000111000 are in drawn encoded names thus we want a look-up table which is found as a Character MAP:
44 0 obj <</Length 2732>>
stream /CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 12 dict begin begincmap /CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (F1+0) /Ordering (T1UV) /Supplement 0 >> def /CMapName /F1+0 def /CMapType 2 def 1 begincodespacerange <02> <ff> endcodespacerange

100 beginbfchar
<02> <041C>
<05> <0434>
<06> <0443>
<07> <043D>
<08> <0430>
<09> <0440>
<0a> <043E>
<0b> <044B>
<0e> <043C>
<0f> <0438>
<10> <0442>
<11> <0441>
<12> <043B>
<13> <0432>
<14> <041A>
<15> <044F>
<16> <041E>
<17> <0431>
<18> <0449>
<19> <0433>
<1a> <0447>
<1b> <0425>
<1c> <0418>
<1d> <0445>
<1e> <0111>
<1f> <0107>
<20> <0020>
<21> <010D>
<22> <0417>
<23> <044A>
<24> <044C>
<25> <0410>
<26> <043F>
<27> <044E>
<2b> <010C>
<2c> <002C>
<2d> <011B>
<2e> <002E>
<2f> <0420>
<30> <0030>
<31> <0411>
<32> <0032>
<33> <041D>
<34> <0034>
<35> <0446>
<36> <0036>
<37> <044D>
<38> <0437>
<39> <045E>
<3a> <003A>
<3b> <042F>
<3c> <0424>
<3d> <0412>
<3e> <0421>
<3f> <0426>
<40> <0413>
<4b> <0452>
<57> <0458>
<58> <0448>
<5b> <013D>
<5c> <0423>
<5d> <0457>
<5e> <041F>
<5f> <004B>
<60> <0057>
<7b> <003B>
<7c> <0456>
<7d> <0422>
<7e> <041B>
<7f> <042D>
<80> <002D>
<81> <045C>
<82> <0144>
<83> <0414>
<84> <045B>
<85> <042E>
<86> <0419>
<87> <0428>
<88> <0427>
<89> <0037>
<8c> <0429>
<8d> <0038>
<8e> <0031>
<8f> <0033>
<90> <2019>
<91> <042B>
<92> <0039>
<93> <0035>
<94> <FB02>
<95> <042C>
<96> <002F>
<97> <0160>
<98> <2116>
<99> <017D>
<9a> <2013>
<9b> <0444>
<9c> <0023>
<9d> <0161>
<9e> <017E>
<9f> <007C>
endbfchar

Thus 0011000000111000 in human terms <08> = <0430> which as "Unicode" graphical encoding will be Unicode Character “а” (U+0430)
Which makes sense as that's what it appears to be drawn in the centre however if we alter the <08> to <02> we find the graphics are nothing like Unicode Character “М” (U+041C)it looks more like an s

so in summary there is no easy way with PDF to be certain what code will extract as what text or what graphics without disassemble the Font internals.
It is simply CID = 8

What we need is the font map where we could reset the font to Unicode from
02 03 04 05 06
07 08 09 etc.


Could you please tell what tools you use here to analyze the internals of PDF documents?
